# How to align two divs side by side when one has margin auto

Tags: html, css, margin

I have a div that has `margin: auto` so it can float in the center of the page. This page also has a zoom feature that zooms in on that element and I want there to be a `min-margin-left` on that element.

I have tried creating a new element that has a fixed width, but when I use `float: left` on both of those elements it doesn't work, and the one that has a fixed width (blue) floats on top of the other one (red).

I tried looking at other questions, but they do not deal with a div that has `margin: auto`, and a question about `min-margin` doesn't deal with two elements.

Here's my current code:

```css
.main_field {
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  height: 100px;
  border: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 75px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div style="background-color: blue; height: 100px; display: inline-block; width: 50px;"></div>
<iframe class="main_field "></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the display - to make your centering work you need the element to be a block:

```css
.papertextfield {
  width: 200px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: red;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<iframe name="textfield" id="textareathingy" class="papertextfield"></iframe>
```

To fake a minimum margin you can use a container with padding:

```css
.papertextfield {
  width: 200px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: red;
  display: block;
}

.container {
  padding-left: 60px;
  padding-right: 60px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <iframe name="textfield" id="textareathingy" class="papertextfield"></iframe>
</div>
```